# change route and send message using socketio but socketio is working

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>

   <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

            var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

            socket.on('connect',()=>{
                console.log('connected');
               document.querySelector('#submit').onclick =() =>{
                const user= document.querySelector('#user').value;
                const room = document.querySelector('#room').value;
                socket.emit('join',{'user':user,'room':room});
                console.log('emitted');
                return false;
               };

            });

        });

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="new-task" action="{{ url_for('chat') }}" method="post">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus id="user" placeholder="username"> 
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autofocus id="room" placeholder="room">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="join">     
    </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

localhost:5000 open index.html page , when i click on submit only socketio is working but url is not being changed .

```
import os
import requests

from flask import Flask,jsonify,render_template,request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO,emit,join_room,leave_room,send

from werkzeug import secure_filename



app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio=SocketIO(app)



@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/chat" ,methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    print("running chat")
    return render_template("chat.html")


@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    username = data['user']
    room = data['room']
    join_room(room)
    emit('chat',{'username':username},room=room)
    print("room has been allocated")
```

*when i did only url_for without socketio i was able to change route* but now it does not seem to work. in console and cmd i am able to see socketio working but **chat route** is not working

Comment: Did you look in the browser console for errors or messages?

Comment: no error is displayed in console

Comment: i am able to change like this  window.location="http://localhost:5000/chat" but no idea what wrong with this.